# Deploy RuleApps to the Business Rules service on Bluemix using an Ant task

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I work with IBM ODM and am deploying a RuleApp to the Business Rules service on Bluemix. Is it possible to do so using the Ant task `res-deploy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could use the `res-deploy` Ant task by specifying the `hostname`, `portnumber`, `secured`, and `password` attributes, as follows:

```
< target name="deploy-ruleapp" >
        < res-deploy hostname="brsv2-99999999.ng.bluemix.net"
         mergingpolicy="ADD_AT_END_MERGING_POLICY" 
         portnumber="443" 
         secured="true" 
         userid="resAdmin" 
         password="xxxxxxxxxxxx" file="myruleapp.jar" / >
< / target >
```

The `hostname` was retrieved from the URL in the Connection settings tab.